# Can Hot Network Questions honor tag filters?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, filtering

If a particular community has a favorite tag, I would like for that question in the Hot Network Questions list to highlight.  If I have a tag set to ignore, it will either grey out or not show at all (as determined by my preferences for that community and tag.)

It seems like there is *some* customization in this list because I've ignored certain communities and those do not show up in this list.  It would be cool to take this one step further.